# Xna custom VertexElementFormat and VertexElementUsage?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm a little confused and not sure how or if this is possible, but is it possible to create custom ones?  VertexElementFormat doesn't contain the type I want to use which is byte3 and I have no idea how I could add that to it :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. For your purposes, you can probably use `Byte4` or `Color`.

These settings tell the GPU how to decode the data you send it and place it in shader registers. They are not extensible.

Note that you can have more than one `Position` or more than one `Color` (for examples) by setting the `UsageIndex` in your `VertexElement`.